# Date format for paypal invoice due date?

Tags: php

I'm using following code for paypal invoice due date

```
$aryData['dueDate'] = "2011-12-31T05:38:48Z";
```

How to generate dynamic date format in php ?

Comment: A quick glance at the PHP manual would answer your question.  Use the Date function of course.. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: See also: http://php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following:

```
$aryData['dueDate'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
```

If you wish to generate the formatted date from a specified date then add a second parameter of a Unix timestamp.

For example:

```
$aryData['dueDate'] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", strtotime("-1 day"));
```